# How to Install GNU Parallel on Windows 10 using git-bash

Tags: windows, bash, unix, git-bash, gnu-parallel

Has anyone been able to successfully use GNU Parallel on Windows 10 with git-bash?  **Is it possible?** - If so, how?

---

**Background:**
I'm having trouble installing GNU Parallel and using it, and it got me thinking - *maybe git-bash is holding me back?* I'm sure if I installed Ubuntu through WSL I wouldn't have any problems running GNU Parallel.  But I wanted to know if I could do this in git-bash first.

Comment: I'm sure Ole Tange will advise you, since he is the author, but in the meantime, be aware that **GNU Parallel** is a Perl script, so you are going to need a Perl interpreter whatever you do.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I appreciate your feedback and information.  I hope somebody has the answer because for the life of me I can't find this anywhere on google.  I guess it's confusing for me because I'm more of a pure unix guy - this whole gitbash shell running on windows thing is crazy to me.

Comment: You and me both, I don't understand the whole gibberish shell (oops, I meant *"gitbash"*) malarkey on Windows either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just installed `git-bash` on a Microsoft Windows 10 machine and had no problems installing GNU Parallel.

It is by no means well tested on git-bash, but basic functionality clearly works.

> I'm having trouble installing GNU Parallel

Maybe you can post the error you get when running:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

Comment: I hope you still follow this question @Ole Tange. I have a problem when trying to install GNU parallel in windows and I don't have any solution to fix it. I tried to use your solution above, but it's still not working. 
1. There is a warning on my computer about GnuPG with this information
`GnuPG (gpg) is not installed so the signature cannot be checked.
This means that if the code has been changed by criminals, you will not discover that!
Continue anyway? (y/n)`

2. If I choose Y, there is a new issue.
`10seconds_install: line 123: cd: $'parallel-20190922\r': No such file or directory`

Comment: 3. I tried to fix it by using an older version, it seems to be Ok. But I don't have any executable file which can run on windows. I can't see any error which is showing on my console screen, I think I should show all messages to you but I can't because of the character limitation. So, I guess the error is below:
`Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.`
The last info I received is: `installed globally22`

Comment: `installed globally` means it is installed in `/usr/local/bin`. So that dir should be in your `$PATH`. I am puzzled why you get the `\r`, because I just tested and I do not get that on my `git-bash` installation. The only why I can make sense of it, is if your version of `sort` inserts the `\r`. You can replace `sort` with: `perl -e 'print sort <>'`.

Comment: I think this bash script for install GNU parallel to windows and there is no `/usr/local/bin` in windows. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes it is wrong: When running in git-bash it will emulate a /usr/local/bin dir. So that is not the issue.

Comment: May I suggest that if this does not solve your issue, that you post a new question and include the full output? It will make it easier to see if I get exactly the same or if there are subtle differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200282/discussion-between-hiep-dang-and-ole-tange).

Comment: @OleTange this link isn't working https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/10seconds_install. Can you give us the right link?

Comment: @RK3 Savannah had a downtime yesterday. The link is fine now.

Comment: @OleTange Hi, can you please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60797246/10155936) question ?

Comment: Installation runs, but doesn't work for me:
```
$ parallel echo ::: foo bar
sh: -c: option requires an argument
sh: -c: option requires an argument
sh: -c: option requires an argument
```

Comment: @NiklasHolm Post a new question. Include the full output of `parallel -Dall echo ::: foo`. Check that it is not covered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797246/how-do-i-get-gnu-parallel-to-work-on-git-bash-in-windows-7