# Running two python scripts with bash file

Tags: python, windows, bash

I would like to run two python scripts at the same time on my lap top without any decreasing in their calculation's speed.

I have searched and saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently) saying that we should use `bash` file.
I have searched but I did not understand what should I do and how to run those scrips with this way called `bash`.

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

I am inexperienced in it and I need your professional advice.
I do not understand how to do that, where and how.
I am using Windows 64bit.

Best

**`PS: The answer I checked the mark is a way to run in parallel two tasks, but it does not decrease the calculation time for two parallel tasks at all.`**

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: open a terminal and run the command `python script1.py &`
`python script2.py &` ( ubuntu /linux based system ) you will be able to run the script without affecting on other performance

Comment: @quamrana windows

Comment: @prashantrana I am using windows. so just needs to write  `python script1.py & python script2.py &` in command prompt? and every thing will be right?

Comment: @MaY yes just 1 script at one time

Comment: @prashantrana well I want two proces at same time without decreasing the speed

Comment: @MaY yeah it will do it , what i meant was run `python script1.py &` click enter and then run `python script2.py &` in terminal

Comment: @MaY, I see your update and it is absolutely not correct that GNU parallel does not decrease overall computation time. While I don't have any visibility of what you are doing, here's a demonstration of how GNU parallel increase computation time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl8LO2jcvMc

Comment: And this one is by the author of GNU parallel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can install [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) on Windows under Git Bash ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451011/3787051)), then you can run the two scripts on separate CPUs this way:

```
▶ (cat <<EOF) | parallel --jobs 2
python script1.py
python script2.py
EOF
```

Note from the parallel man page:

```
   --jobs N
       Number of jobslots on each machine. Run up to N jobs in parallel.
       0 means as many as possible. Default is 100% which will run one job per
       CPU on each machine.
```

---

Note that the question has been updated to state that parallelisation does not improve calculation time, which is not generally a correct statement.

While the benefits of parallelisation are highly machine- and workload-dependent, parallelisation significantly improves the processing time of CPU-bound processes on multi-core computers.

Here is a demonstration based on calculating 50,000 digits of Pi using Spigot's algorithm ([code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967370/3787051)) on my quad-core MacBook Pro:

Single task (52s):

```
▶ time python3 spigot.py
...
python3 spigot.py 52.73s user 0.32s system 98% cpu 53.857 total
```

Running the same computation twice in GNU parallel (74s):

```
▶ (cat <<EOF) | time parallel --jobs 2                                                                                                                                   
python3 spigot.py                                                                                                                                                      
python3 spigot.py                                                                                                                                                      
EOF        
...
parallel --jobs 2  74.19s user 0.48s system 196% cpu 37.923 total
```

Of course this is on a system that is busy running an operating system and all my other apps, so it doesn't halve the processing time, but it is a big improvement all the same.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018124/3787051) related Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have git-bash on my window. 
I have this one in git bash command windows
`YMa@Yong21-PC MINGW64 ~
$`
so shoul I write your code after $?

Comment: what is `▶ cat` and etc. sorry for such a questions.

Comment: and could I ask you how to install gnu parallel on windoes?

Comment: The ▶ is my prompt. Ignore that. Install Git Bash, and then type everything exactly as you see it in my answer, with the ▶ character. As for installing Git Bash, did you follow the link to the related Stack Overflow question where there are instructions?

Comment: no because it does not open for me. I just had git bash before. but I do not know how to insall gnu plot using that

Comment: Sorry. Here are some instructions on installing Git Bash https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWboGsc6CqI

Comment: And then follow the instructions here to install GNU parallel https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451011/3787051

Comment: yes I saw it before and installed git bash. Now I am asking how to install Gnu parallel. because I found one using sudo apt

Comment: `bash: 10seconds_install: No such file or directory
`

Comment: `$ wget https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/10seconds_install
bash: wget: command not found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189202/discussion-between-alex-harvey-and-ma-y).

Answer (score 2):

I use a batch file which contains these lines:

```
start python script1.py
start python script2.py
```

This opens a new window for each `start` statement.

Comment: won't `call python script1.py &` be better choice

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The two scripts run sequentially, not concurrently.

Comment: I have two question here. should I write it on `command prompt` . and another one this run both them in parallel? I mean if you open just two Python scripts with IDL your running time will increase. But I do not want to have longer time. Is it possible?

Comment: You can open two command prompts yourself and run `script1` in one and `script2` in the other, or, type the above lines in one command prompt, or use a batch file to start them.

Comment: So far so good. The let me finish my scripts that I have ran them with IDLE, I think they will be finished within 6 hours. Then I will run it.  Each of them lasts for 21 hours, and when I run them both together the time is 26 hours. so I should try to see is it possible to have that 21 hours with this way or not.

Answer (score 1):

A quite easy way to run parallel jobs of every kind is using nohup. This redirect the output to a file call nohup.out (by default). In your case you should just write:

```
nohup python script1.py > output_script1 &
nohup python script2.py > output_script2 &
```

That's it. With nohup you can also logout and the script will be continuing until they have finished